# Post-hoc pairwise comparison in `anova.cca` (package `vegan`)

Tags: r, anova, canonical-correlation, vegan

Is there a way to perform a post-hoc pairwise comparison following `anova.cca`, for categorical independent variables with >2 levels, in the same sense as `TukeyHSD` following `aov`?

For example, please consider the following result (modified from `vegan` documentation):

```r
library(vegan)
data(dune)
data(dune.env)
fit = cca(dune ~ Management, dune.env)
anova(fit, by = "terms")

## Permutation test for cca under reduced model
## Terms added sequentially (first to last)
## Permutation: free
## Number of permutations: 999
## 
## Model: cca(formula = dune ~ Management, data = dune.env)
##            Df ChiSquare      F Pr(>F)   
## Management  3   0.60384 2.1307  0.002 **
## Residual   16   1.51143                 
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

According to the output, we conclude that the effect of `Management` on species composition in `dune` is significant.

However, what is we want to furthermore evaluate whether the pairwise differences between levels of `Management`

```r
dune.env$Management

##  [1] SF BF SF SF HF HF HF HF HF BF BF SF SF NM NM SF NM NM NM NM
## Levels: BF HF NM SF
```

are significant? That is, whether species composition differs between `BF` and `HF`, between `BF` and `NM`, etc., for all possible pairs of the four `Management` levels?

---

This answer:
[Constrained ordination (CAP) pairwise ANOVA](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/575560/constrained-ordination-cap-pairwise-anova)
by `vegan` package author offers (in "Third alternative") a promising pathway, using `model.matrix` to generate dummy variables for the pairwise comparisons and then using them as independent variables, as in:

```r
dune.env2 = data.frame(model.matrix(~ Management, data=dune.env))
fit = cca(dune ~ ., dune.env2)
anova(fit, by = "terms")

## Permutation test for cca under reduced model
## Terms added sequentially (first to last)
## Permutation: free
## Number of permutations: 999
## 
## Model: cca(formula = dune ~ X.Intercept. + ManagementHF + ManagementNM + ManagementSF, data = dune.env2)
##              Df ChiSquare      F Pr(>F)   
## ManagementHF  1   0.14772 1.5638  0.121   
## ManagementNM  1   0.28927 3.0622  0.002 **
## ManagementSF  1   0.16685 1.7663  0.050 * 
## Residual     16   1.51143                 
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

which suggests that species composition in `BF` differs from `NM` and `SF`, but not from species composition in `HF`.

---

My questions thus are:

1. Is the above solution correct?
2. Would it be correct to repeat it (three more times, in this case) to obtain the significance of the pairwise comparisons against each of the possible "reference" levels other than `BF`?
3. If not, is there another way to obtain pairwise comparisons following `anova.cca`?